# Iterating over JSON and rendering table elements yield no result

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to build a reusable table component in React but having no luck so far when it comes to rendering my `<td>`s.

I'm passing my required props from `TableList` component to my `TableRow` component like this:

```
    const TableList = props => {
    const { listData, listHeaders } = props;

    return (
        <table className="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    {listHeaders.map(header => (
                        <th scrope="col" key={header}>
                            {header}
                        </th>
                    ))}
                    <th scope="col" />
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {listData.map(data => (
                    <TableRow
                        key={data.id}
                        data={data}
                        handleClick={props.handleClick}
                    />
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
};
```

and in `TableRow` I can iterate over my JSON objects just fine, but my  element isn't rendering. I'm getting no errors but my `<tr>` element in the DOM has no child in it. Here's my `TableRows` component:

```
    const TableRow = props => {
    const { data } = props;

    return (
        <tr>
            {Object.keys(data).forEach(function(item) {
                console.log(data[item]); // This prints out my JSON objects just fine
                <td key={item}>data[item]</td>; // But this element isn't rendering in the DOM
            })}
        </tr>
    );
};
```

I've tried assigning my JSON objects to an array for `.map()` navigation but that too, came up with the same result. Also I've tried moving various elements like `<tbody>` and `<tr>` up and down the component tree to no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to return JSX elements from your loop. Like

```
return (
  <tr>
    {Object.keys(data).map(function(item) {
      console.log(data[item]); // This prints out my JSON objects just fine
      return <td key={item}>data[item]</td>; // But this element isn't rendering in the DOM
    })}
  </tr>
);
```

[Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) returns `undefined`. And at the moment, you're rendering `undefined`. You can use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which is used to transform the input array and returns an array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix two things

- You need change `forEach()` with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) because **`forEach()` ways return `undefined`**.
- You should use `()` instead of `{}`.If you want to use `{}` use `return` before jsx inside function

Here is code.

```
<tr>
   {Object.keys(data).map((item) => (
         <td key={item}>data[item]</td>; // But this element isn't rendering in the DOM
    )}
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const TableRow = props => {
const { data } = props;

return (
    <tr>
        {Object.keys(data).forEach(function(item) {
            console.log(data[item]); // This prints out my JSON objects just fine

            <td key={item}>data[item]</td>; // But this element isn't rendering in the DOM
        })}
    </tr>
    );
};
```

The Object.keys(data).forEach() isn't right here, it doesn' return anythung. 
You should do a Object.keys(data).map, and for each key you should return a jsx.

```
const TableRow = props => {
const { data } = props;

    return (
        <tr>
            {Object.keys(data).map(function(item) {
                return <td key={item}>data[item]</td>; // But this element isn't rendering in the DOM
            })}
        </tr>
    );
};
```

Should work prefectly.